# Print the rows that have the largest combination across two columns (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Tell me how to display lines as in the example through window functions.
The algorithm is as follows:
Group by “clusterid”, which is not null. And if “issuedate” and “operdate” are equal in each section, then we display all lines with “Publid” for which there is the largest number of unique combinations “publid + inn”.

Example

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
```

Result

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
```

I've been thinking about how to write the code for a long time, but I can't. There is the following idea, but not entirely correct.

```
 SELECT a.*
       FROM (SELECT m.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterid order by issuedate desc, operdate desc, count(inn) desc) AS rn
              FROM table as m 
              GROUP BY publid
              WHERE clusterid is not null
              ) AS a
        WHERE a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it:

```
SQL> with test (inn, publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate) as
  2    (select 333, 1, 12, date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  3     select 222, 1, 12, date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  4     select 333, 2, 12, date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  5     select 222, 2, 12, date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  6     select 111, 2, 12, date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-05' from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select inn, publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate,
 10       row_number() over (partition by clusterid, inn order by publid desc) rn
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select inn, publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate
 14  from temp
 15  where rn = 1;

       INN     PUBLID  CLUSTERID ISSUEDAT OPERDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- -------- --------
       111          2         12 01.01.21 05.01.21
       222          2         12 01.01.21 05.01.21
       333          2         12 01.01.21 05.01.21

SQL>
```